# How to Use Three.js animation in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image: Example Gif]I wish to implement this type of animation in flutter using THREE.js I search THREE.js plugin in dart package but it's not available . How to achieve this.

Comment: Hi! A quick search on pub.dev will find you multiple implentations of ThreeJS for Dart (https://pub.dev/packages?q=three.js). I have tried none of them so I can't guarantee quality. Another option would be to port Three.js by yourself to a flutter plugin. For web this could be done quite easily, supporting IOS and Android would become a more dificult job. The last option which I would recommend is using Rive. Rive is a easy to use animation tool. Which integrates perfectly with Flutter. See: https://rive.app/ and https://pub.dev/packages/rive